# Running jenkins pipelines in docker on a jenkins instance running in docker can't find docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to deploy a Jenkins instance inside a Docker container then configure a pipeline build within a Docker container. I'm following the installation instructions on the Jenkins website and I now have this

docker file:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11

USER root

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        docker 

USER jenkins
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins docker-workflow:1.28
```

compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.3" 

services:
  docker:
    image: docker:dind
    restart: on-failure
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - ${JENKINS_HOME}:/var/jenkins_home
      - ${JENKINS_CERTS}:/certs/client
    ports:
      - "2376:2376"
    environment:
      DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: /certs
  jenkins:
    build: services/jenkins 
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - "docker"
    volumes:
      - ${JENKINS_HOME}:/var/jenkins_home
      - ${JENKINS_CERTS}:/certs/client:ro
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    environment:
      DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
      DOCKER_CERT_PATH: /certs/client
      DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
```

the Jenkinsfile I'm trying to run looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent { 
        docker { image 'gcc:12.1.0' } 
    }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'cmake -S . -B _output'
                sh 'cmake --build _output'
            }
        }
   }
}
```

When I try and run the jenkinsfile through a basic pipeline I get the following error

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . gcc:12.1.0
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/my-pipeline@tmp/durable-231ff8ae/script.sh: 1: docker: not found
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker pull gcc:12.1.0
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/my-pipeline@tmp/durable-b0322a5b/script.sh: 1: docker: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run a Docker agent within the Jenkins Docker container. So basically Jenkins node which is already running in Docker will try to start another Docker container(with image`'gcc:12.1.0'`) and run your pipeline within that. For this to work you need docker installed in your Jenkins Base image(`jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11`).

**Update:** I just realized you are already installing docker. Try installing `install -y docker-ce-cli` in your base image.